# I invite X and Y to add "their" or "your"

Tags: grammar

Which is correct:

> I invite X and Y to add **their** presentations to the repository.

or

> I invite X and Y to add **your** presentations to the repository.

X and Y are personal names.

Comment: More context is needed: who are you talking to or writing to? If you're talking in the absence of X and Y, then the first with _their_ is appropriate. If it's e.g. a conference audience with X and Y present, then the second with _your_.

Comment: I'm writing this in a group channel on Slack.

Comment: If X and Y are direct recipients of your message, then I'd use _your_. In this case, both would be correct: saying it with _their_, you're talking to everybody else, knowing that X and Y also receive the message. Saying it with _your_, you're talking directly to the two, which is more polite to them but the others have to show some tolerance and patience for doing business among only the three of you in front of everybody.

Comment: @BenceMélykúti In practice, if X and Y are present, the second one might be used - but it is not correct. If you are referring to third persons you need to speak in the third person.

Comment: All right. To summarise, grammatically only the first one is correct but life wouldn't stop if you used the second one in the given context.

Comment: Apposition is needed for "I invite you, X and Y, to add your presentations to the repository." Is the normal unmarked form "Are you coming, John?" or (speaking directly to John) "Is John coming?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of a problem arises when one is saying something in the presence of (or posting something to) a group of people, that concerns some, but not all, members of that group. In such a situation one has to decide whether

(1) to treat the communication as *addressed* to the group as a whole, and to leave it to the *content* of the communication to make it clear whom it concerns,

or

(2) to treat the communication as addressed only to the people whom it concerns (X an Y in OP’s case), and to regard everybody else in the group as merely allowed to hear the communication (if one makes this choice, one is not speaking *to* the group as a whole, but merely in its presence).

If one chooses (1) in OP’s case, one cannot use the second person for X and Y, because the communication is not addressed specifically to them, but to the group as a whole. The references to X and Y in such a case have to be made in the third person: ‘I invite X and Y to add *their* presentations . . .’ .

On the other hand, if one chooses (2), one has to begin the communication by making it clear that one is addressing only X and Y, and not the group as a whole. If one does that, one should use the second person for them. One may thus say something like ‘You, X and Y, are invited to add *your* presentations . . .’ . If one is speaking in physical space, one will likely supplement that by turning towards X and Y. (On Stack Exchange, a similar function is performed by using @ in comments.)

The difference between (1) and (2) is subtle, and, in the rapid flow of everyday interactions, people often don’t have the time to consciously choose between them. They thus sometimes start a communication in a manner that fits (1), using the third person for somebody, and then shift to using the second person for the same individual, which would fit (2), but does not fit (1). We thus get the formulations like ‘I invite X and Y to add your presentations . . .’ . Such formulations mix the third and the second person in a way that is ungrammatical, but the grammatical mistake that they embody is, under the circumstances, understandable.